# How do I search a list for a predicate

Tags: scheme

I want to create a higher order function that takes in a S-Expr and predicate as arguments and and returns a list of all atoms inside the given s-expression which pass the given predicate

For example

```
(fetch number? '(the (quick 6 fox 8 9) slick 2))
```

and scheme will return `(6 8 9 2)`

Hopefully someone can point me in the righ direction,learning it myself at home

What I have started with

```
(define (fetch pred? ls)
    (cond
        [(null? '())]
        [(number?)]
        [(symbol?)]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build a solution using the template for iterating over a list of lists, taking care of also *flattening* the results as we build them. For example, this is one way to solve the problem:

```
(define (fetch pred lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())  ; if the list is empty, return the empty list
        ((not (pair? lst)) ; if the current element is an atom
         (if (pred lst)    ; then test it using the predicate
             (list lst)    ; if the condition holds, add the current element to result
             '()))         ; otherwise ignore the current element
        (else (append (fetch pred (car lst))     ; recursive step: traverse both the car
                      (fetch pred (cdr lst)))))) ; and the cdr part of the list
```

The above is how you'd write the solution from scratch. However, in idiomatic Scheme it's recommended to split the problem in smaller parts and use existing procedures (or write general, reusable procedures) and compose them to form an answer. For instance, in Racket we can do this:

```
; test if an object is an atom
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (null? x))
       (not (pair? x))))

 ; map over a list of lists    
(define (map* func lst)
  (if (atom? lst)
      (func lst)
      (map (curry map* func) lst)))

; "fetch" by first mapping and then flattening the input list
(define (fetch pred lst)
  (flatten
   (map* (lambda (x) (if (pred x) x '()))
         lst)))
```

Alternatively, we can also `flatten` first and then `filter`, as suggested by @user448810. Anyway, the result is as expected:

```
(fetch number? '(the (quick 6 fox 8 9) slick 2))
=> '(6 8 9 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach to the problem. It uses an accumulator instead of `append` when handling pairs, to eliminate the repeated copying of list structure over and over again which is done by `append`:

```
(define (flat-filter pred x)
  (let recur ((x x)
              (initial '()))
    (cond ((null? x) initial)
          ((pair? x)
           (recur (car x) (recur (cdr x) initial)))
          ((pred x) (cons x initial)) ;; the one CONS call per element added
          (else initial))))
```

This is probably a more advanced solution than Óscar López's, but it easily allows abstracting out into a folding function (argument order deliberately chosen to mirror that of `fold` and `fold-right` that are provided with most Scheme implementations as part of [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)):

```
(define (flat-fold-right func initial x)
  (cond ((null? x) initial)
        ((pair? x)
         (flat-fold-right func (flat-fold-right func initial (cdr x)) (car x)))
        (else (func x initial)))) ;; the one call to FUNC per element of input

(define (flat-filter pred x)
  (flat-fold-right (lambda (elem res)
                     (if (pred elem)
                         (cons elem res)
                         res))
                   '() x))
```

Bonus freebies:

```
(define (flat-map func x)
  (flat-fold-right (lambda (elem res)
                     (cons (func elem) res))
                   '() x))

(define (flatten x)
  (flat-fold-right cons '() x))
```

Comment: won't it be a very heavy recursion though, the car-cdr recursion that you're using in both `flat-filter` and `flat-fold-right`? It's not running under *lazy* evaluation here...

Comment: @WillNess Remember that the car-side "recursion" is tail recursion. It's pretty similar to traditional left-folding algorithms that do recursion only for car and tail-recursion for cdr. In fact, just by swapping `car` and `cdr` in `flat-fold-right`, you have `flat-fold-left`. :-)

Comment: you're right, this make all the difference. the depth of stack frames chain is never more than the depth of the tree. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to break your problem into two parts.

One procedure, traditionally called `flatten`, removes all the nesting from a list; thus, `(flatten '(the (quick 6 fox 8 9) slick 2))` would return `(the quick 6 fox 8 9 slick 2)`.

The second procedure, traditionally called `filter`, then scans the output of `flatten` and returns only those items that pass the predicate; thus `(filter number? (flatten '(the (quick 6 fox 8 9) slick 2)))` would return `(6 8 9 2)`.

That means you could write `(define (fetch pred? ls) (filter pred? (flatten ls)))` to define your function.

I'll leave it to you to write `flatten` and `filter`. Both are simple, and both are useful in other contexts than your question. You should have both in your standard toolkit; [I do](http://programmingpraxis.com/standard-prelude/).

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with all data types. It uses a backtracking list when it needs to follow both car and cdr.

```
(define (filter-tree pred? tree)
  (reverse
   (let loop ((acc '()) (tree tree) (back '()))
     (cond ((pred? tree) (cons tree acc))
           ((not (pair? tree)) 
            (if (null? back) acc (loop acc (car back) (cdr back))))
           ((pred? (car tree)) 
            (loop (cons (car tree) acc) (cdr tree) back))
           ((pair? (car tree)) 
            (loop acc (car tree) (cons (cdr tree) back)))
           (else (loop acc (cdr tree) back))))))

;; test data
(define sub '(quick 6 fox 8 9))
(define end '(slick 2))
(define lst `(the ,sub ,@end))

;; tests    
(filter-tree number? lst) ; ==> (6 8 9 2)
(filter-tree (lambda (x) (equal? x lst)) lst) ; ==> ((the (quick 6 fox 8 9) slick 2))
(filter-tree (lambda (x) (or (equal? x sub) (equal? x end))) lst) ; ==> ((quick 6 fox 8 9) (slick 2))
(filter-tree (lambda (x) (equal? x end)) lst) ; ==> ((slick 2))
```